# Is there a name for "singing between registers", as if one as at the end of their range, to produce multiple notes?

Tags: technique, voice, terminology

I've been experimenting with singing a note and then slowly devoicing it or applying less pressure with my, usually near the top of my chest / modal(?) register, and trying to get that harsh sound where it sounds like there's a two tones plus a bunch of noise / interference. I'm not a vocalist, so I don't know what this would be called, but it reminds me of multiphonics (both on bowed string instruments and wind instruments). I tried searching for the term "vocal multiphonics", but that's already taken by brass players.

I don't think it's screaming, and it doesn't feel like creaky voice. Yodeling seems close, but that would involve flipping completely between registers rather than staying in between. So what is it called?

Comment: Can you give an example of what it sounds like?

Comment: I don’t have a name for it but it sounds like the sort of wailing, pained, angry sounds that Coltrane produced on tenor sax, especially on the Coltrane Sound album. Applied artfully it could be a really strong effect in a blues or jazz solo. Is that what you have in mind?

Comment: You mean a split note? Best example I can think of off the top of my head is [Prefab Sprout - Goodbye Lucille #1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V84TSOukdYk) at around 3:40

Comment: Overtone/harmonic/throat singing? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overtone_singing or https://www.oberton.org/en/overtone-singing/what-is-overtone-singing/ More than one note at the same time, so the closest to wind/string multiphonics.

Comment: Hey, you might want to check out the beatboxing technique of "double voice" - from what I understand, some of them describe their technique as being right in-between the falsetto and the chest voice, it might be worth looking at if you haven't already. Then again, the beatbox community has a long history of disagreeing on names for sounds ;)

Comment: Try searching "vocal multiphonics" again. For example : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiphonic#Vocal_multiphonics

Comment: @user45266 I think I'm actually describing "polyphonic voice" (though I only heard this term in this random video I found teaching double voice), but it's a pretty close match.

Comment: @awelotta Does my answer capture the sound you're describing? In no, I've also heard of "polyphonic voice" from a video that related to producing a sort of whistling sound while singing but that can be controlled separately from the main pitch. I'd be happy to add that to my answer if you think it's relevant to what you're looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are ***vocal multiphonics***.

There is an instructional video which describes the technique in very similar terms to the OP.

> To get that extra bit of overtones going on, you just go to the break point of your falsetto (Glen Soulis, 0:51 in linked video)

There is a detailed discussion of a variety of vocal multiphonics techniques in [An introduction to Extended Vocal Techniques](http://www.ex-tempore.org/kavash/kavash.htm), including "egressive" techniques, of which the present technique would be one. It also includes numerous references to musical examples of the techniques discussed.